# Connect the primary monitor to a Windows desktop after boot

Tags: windows, hdmi

Recently, I bought an HDMI switcher and connected my Macbook and Windows 11 desktop to share my single display.

The problem is that when I use the monitor with my Macbook and start my Windows desktop (as the monitor is connected to my Macbook, no monitor is connected to the desktop), the display shows nothing after I switch the display to my Windows.

My question is how I can avoid this problem **without** rebooting my Windows with the connection to the display.
While rebooting Windows is a solution, I prefer not to because I regularly use my Macbook when I start my Windows.

Any comment is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Windows will uninstall a HDMI port when the cable is not connected, and install the HDMI port upon connecting the monitor.

Because of this, the only way to get this to work, is to use a switcher that has active ports. Active ports mean, they will emulate a monitor connected even if the switch is set to the other.

The solution is going to be, to buy a HDMI switcher that keeps the HDMI port connected even if the switch is to the other port.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That's definitely what I want to hear. Do you have any idea of the HDMI I should consider?

Comment: No. I have only needed to get one once, and it was more than 10 years ago.